# GetPropertiesOfSecretVersionsAsync does not contain a definition of 'WhereAwait'

Tags: identityserver4, azure-keyvault, x509certificate2

I'm just setting up our IdentityServer4 install to pull certificates from Azure Key Vault using this for guidance.
https://damienbod.com/2020/04/09/using-certificates-from-azure-key-vault-in-asp-net-core/

The above uses a depreciated package so I'm updating the code to use the latest. I found this blog post which also helped
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/keyvault-secrets-rotation-management-in-bulk/ba-p/2145339

The issue I have is that I can't seem to get *GetPropertiesOfSecretVersionsAsync* to work, the code from the latter example above shows an error "*GetPropertiesOfSecretVersionsAsync does not contain a definition of 'WhereAwait'*"

```
var versions = await client.GetPropertiesOfSecretVersionsAsync(secret.Name)
                    .WhereAwait(p => new ValueTask<bool>(p.Enabled.GetValueOrDefault() == true))
                    .OrderByDescendingAwait(p => new ValueTask<DateTimeOffset>(p.CreatedOn.GetValueOrDefault()))
                    .ToListAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

and even when I try the following I get an error saying that it does not contain a definition of GetAwaiter.

```
var versions = await client.GetPropertiesOfSecretVersionsAsync(secret.Name);
```

I'm not using it but I get the same issue when calling *GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync*. Everything works fine if I use the non async methods.

Has anyone faced this issue or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To get `.WhereAwait()` you will have to call `.ToAsyncEnumerable()` first.